# How to count rows that aren't match between two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

`Users`:

```
ID    LastPaymentDate
1     2017-01-01
2     2018-02-05
3     2018-04-06
5     NULL
```

`ActivityLog`:

```
ID    ActivityDate
1     2017-01-01
1     2017-05-17
3     2018-05-20
```

I need to find out the number of users that have `LastPaymentDate` but doesn't have matched  `ActivityDate`

The output result for the above data is: `2` (`UserID` 3 and 2).

How can I do this?

Comment: Outer join and an Is Null filter

Comment: @nicomp but how you make sure you didn't count the same user twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using a left join approach here:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.LastPaymentDate
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN ActivityLog a
    ON u.ID = a.ID AND u.LastPaymentDate = a.ActivityDate
WHERE
    a.ID IS NULL AND u.LastPaymentDate IS NOT NULL;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: this anti-join pattern is what i would use +10; assuming ID is unique in users, we can wrap this as an inline view `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (   query  )  v`  (Personally, I'd do the the query to return individual rows as shown in the answer, for testing, to verify which rows are being returned, before reducing it to just a count.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I don't think duplicates may be an issue here, because the `Users` table seems to me to have only one entry per user.  In any case, we could fix that by doing `SELECT DISTINCT u.ID`, if the OP really had this need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Users u
WHERE 
    u.LastPaymentDate IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ActivityLog a
        WHERE u.ID  = a.ID  AND u.ActivityDate = a.ActivityDate
    )
```

The good thing about this approach is that it will not count several times the same record in `Users`, even if it has several matching record in the `ActivityLog`.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` might be better, because MySQL [optimizes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3298cd2fb3c4f68c5c5716970b93dad) the `LEFT JOIN` approach notice the "not exists" in the explain output.   *"Not exists .. MySQL was able to do a LEFT JOIN optimization on the query and does not examine more rows in this table for the previous row combination after it finds one row that matches the LEFT JOIN criteria"*  see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) .. This optimization exists atleast in MySQL 5.1+ i believe.

Comment: @RaymondNijland:  it's sort of wonky that that the EXPLAIN output for the anti-join includes "not exists" , and the EXPLAIN for a NOT EXISTS query doesn't. The advantage of the `NOT EXISTS` is that it may be more straightforward for future readers. But even with that, I'm still a big fan of the anti-join pattern; I just wish the syntax for the anti-join was more intuitive i.e. easier for the future reader to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this. My resolution was to create views to display the fields and the count as columns. Then I did a join between the views to display the net results:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=MySQL CURRENT_USER() SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `subcr_count_x`  AS SELECT `x_subscriptions`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, count(0) AS `cnt` FROM `x_subscriptions` WHERE (`x_subscriptions`.`user_id` > 0) GROUP BY `x_subscriptions`.`user_id` ;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=MySQL CURRENT_USER() SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `subcr_count_y`  AS SELECT `y_subscriptions`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, count(0) AS `cnt` FROM `y_subscriptions` WHERE (`y_subscriptions`.`user_id` > 0) GROUP BY `y_subscriptions`.`user_id`;
```

To select the records where there isn't a match, it does this.

```
SELECT * FROM 
`subcr_count_x` x INNER JOIN 
`subcr_count_y` y ON x.user_id = y.user_id 
WHERE x.cnt != y.cnt
```